# How can I take a simple counter and I want to load the current count into a textbox? 

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, timer

How can I take a simple counter and I want to load the current count into a textbox?

**My code:**

```
count1 = new Timer(count);
count1.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,stopWatch);
count1.start();

private function stopWatch(event:TimerEvent):void{
    var myTextBox:TextField = new TextField();
    myTextBox.text = count1.currentCount;
    addChild(myTextBox);
}
```

**Resulting error:**

> 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type int to an unrelated type String.

Comment: Please use the code formatting guidelines on the right side of the page when you edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are assigning an `int` to the `.text` field. It will only accept a `string` and will not implicitly cast it. Use the `toString` method of `int` supplied to you by the base `Object` class.

```
myTextBox.text = count1.currentCount.toString();
```

See also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237940/convert-an-integer-to-a-string-as3/2237968#2237968) on the same subject.

**Update, regarding comment:**
I would avoid using `addChild` when the event fires. Assuming `stopWatch` is called more than once, the posted code will add a new `TextField` *every* time. Instead, just create it once, but set the `.text` field every time the event fires.

```
// Create text box to show timer output
var myTextBox:TextField = new TextField();
addChild(myTextBox);

// Create timer and start
var count1 = new Timer(count);
count1.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,stopWatch);
count1.start();

// Update text box whenever TIMER event fires
private function stopWatch(event:TimerEvent):void{
  myTextBox.text = count1.currentCount.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked great. However it overlays the numbers, is there anyway for it to replace the previous count?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'overlays the numbers?` If the timer is going off more than once, your `TextField` control is getting added to the screen more than once (via `new` and `addChild`). This could be what you're seeing. I'd recommend doing this once, outside of the event function, and just setting `myTextBox.text` when the event fires.

Comment: Yeah that works. To display the count in milleseconds would i have to multiple the currentCount by a number?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried converting your `int` to a string?  Something like this:

`myTextBox.text = String(count1.currentCount);`

See if that works?