# Why will the correct text not show?

Tags: flash, text, timer

I am creating a Flash project that includes a timer.  I am using the Timer class, but when I test the project the text goes from 00 to 0 instead of going to 01.  In Flash, I have created 2 text fields, for minutes and seconds; I have only made the cod for the second timer.  My code is:

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;


public class Demolition extends MovieClip {

    private var _secTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000, 60);
    private var _minTimer:Timer = new Timer(60000);

    public var _sec:TextField;
    public var _min:TextField;

    public function Demolition() {
        _secTimer.start();
        _secTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, secTimer);

        addEventListener(MouseEvent.RIGHT_CLICK, rightClickHandler);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameHandler);
    }

    private function rightClickHandler(e:MouseEvent) {

    }

    private function frameHandler(e:Event) {

    }

    private function secTimer(e:TimerEvent) {
        trace(e.currentTarget.currentCount);
        if (e.currentTarget.currentCount < 10) {
            _sec.text = "0" + String(e.currentTarget.currentCount);
        } else if (e.currentTarget.currentCount == 60) {
            _secTimer.reset();
            _sec.text = "00";
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[convert an integer to a string as3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237940/convert-an-integer-to-a-string-as3)

Have you tried using 
 `e.currentTarget.currentCount.toString()`
instead of 
`String(e.currentTarget.currentCount)`?

EDIT: actually you shouldn't even need to use string conversion to concatenate an int to a string

Comment: I just tried that and, unfortunately, the same thing happened.

Comment: I don't know much of anything about flash, but should you be starting the timer before you add the event listener?

Comment: Yes, I know this because the timer is able to print the number in the output.

Comment: from reading the adobe blog on Timers https://blogs.adobe.com/pdehaan/2006/07/using_the_timer_class_in_actio.html
I suggest using getTimer() * 1000

Comment: Also if you plan on manually restarting your timer at 60 seconds, you can leave out the second parameter in your Timer constructor, i.e. new Timer(1000)

Comment: I just tried exactly what that says, and it just gave me an error, not sure why.

Comment: can you specify? I meant getTimer / 100 btw

Comment: It said, "1180: Call to a possibly undefined method getTimer."

Comment: oh I don't think getTimer() has anything to do with your timer... it looks like it's just for getting the time elapsed since runtime. If switching start and addEventListener plus using "0" + e.currentTarget.currentCount doesn't work, then I have no idea

Comment: OMG, I AM SOOOO STUPID!  I embedded the font but forgot to check the "All" box.  Thanks for your help though.