# AS3 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type uint to an unrelated type String

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm getting this error :

```
Error 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type uint to an unrelated type String.
```

The `box1` and `box2` are dynamic text boxes. I would like the random number to be put into the dynamic text box.

```
box1.text = num;
box2.text = num2;
var num:uint = Math.floor( Math.random() * 101 )
var num2:uint = Math.floor( Math.random() * 101 )
var right = num * num2
```

Comment: type errors like this mean you are trying to mix incompatible object types. In this case, uint to a string. You need to cast the uint to string before using it. Next time, a simple google search would clear up this very basic issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237940/convert-an-integer-to-a-string-as3

Comment: `box1.text = num.toString();`   or `String(num)`,  or `num + "";`

Comment: There's also the problem that you're trying to use variables that you haven't defined yet. The first two lines should be at the end of your example code. Otherwise you'll get an Exception.

Comment: @DodgerThud I don't agree with you because [the compiler will move all variable declarations to the top of their scope](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9d.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f8c).

Answer (score 0):

The main reason might be that you are trying to place uint value to a string value

```
box1.text = String(num);
box2.text = String(num2);
var num:uint = Math.floor( Math.random() * 101 )
var num2:uint = Math.floor( Math.random() * 101 )
var right = num * num2
```

this might solve the issue , if not reply , I will be happy to help , the reason is that ".text" accept only String values.